# How to make a text string into a bullet list

Tags: list

I have a multi-select box (with a list of countries) on my BuddyPress registration page and would like to display the results on a member's page in a bullet list.

The code below shows a bullet but then still displays the text as a string. Please help.

```
<?php $countries = bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' );
if ( ! empty( $countries ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $countries as $country ) {
        printf( '<li>%s</li>', $country );
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Thank you,

John

Comment: Hi John, this is a PHP question and not related to Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is delimited by a comma `,` you can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string at this point into pieces (an array of items). If your string is separated by something else, such as spaces or `|` then explode that instead.

```
<?php 
//assuming your string might look like: "USA, Canada, Japan, Russia"
$countries = bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' );

$array = explode(",", $countries);
//$array[0] = USA
//$array[1] = Canada
//$array[2] = Japan
//$array[3] = Russia

if ( ! empty( $countries ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $array as $country ) {
        printf( '<li>%s</li>', $country );
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

/* Result
<ul>
<li>USA</li>
<li>Canada</li>
<li>Japan</li>
<li>Russia</li>
</ul>
*/
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it's still displaying as a string (no bullet or spaces). It is delimited by a comma so I copied and pasted the code above.

Comment: Here's the webpage:

http://missionsfund.com/members/janedoe/

Comment: Can you `$var_dump($countries);` and show us the output because its a comma-delimited string as shown then you should be getting the result you desire.